# Alerts for a script with restricted access to tradingview.com

Tags: tradingview-api

I have a restricted script that gives me signals on the chart. I would like to know how I can write a script that will trigger alerts when a signal appears?
The standard notification functions are not suitable. The Pine code is required.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: you need to have full source code of that indicator , then only you will be able to add your standard notification